# What does the sum of reciprocal of primes less than n equal?

Tags: prime-numbers

$ \frac 12+ \frac 13+ \frac 15+  \cdots + \frac 1P$ where 
$P$ is a prime number less than $N$

I have been getting some number approximately $\log\log N$, but I have no nice way of proving it.

Comment: I'm not sure to which extent this is close to what you're looking for, but you might have a look at [Mertens' theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems).

Comment: Mertens theorem should do it: $\sum_{n \leq x} 1/p = \log\log x + B + O(1/\log x)$. This can be proved using Abel summation. An explicit proof is found in Nathanson's Additive Number Theory among several other places.

Comment: A good reference is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504289) article.